# Two foreign keys as primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How would I implement the following tables using hibernate annotations?

[image]

Current code is: *(stripped for brevity)*

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**SocialNetwork**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "social_network")
public class SocialNetwork implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**SocialProfile**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "social_profile")
public class SocialProfile implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="social_network_id")
    public SocialNetwork getSocialNetwork() {
        return socialNetwork;
    }
}
```

Obviously my code is not working correctly right now. Can anyone shed some light onto this?

Comment: You may also consider to add a simple ID column to you social_profile and just add a unique constraint on both FK together. It's nearly the same but much easier to handle, imho

Comment: @stg Thanks for the tip, I added an `id` to the social_profile table and I made the fields unique and not empty. Much simpler this way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need an embeddable SocialProfileId like this :

```
@Embeddable
public class SocialProfileId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long userId;
    @Column(name = "social_network_id")
    private long socialNetworkId;
}
```

then, your SocialProfile entity will look like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "social_profile")
public class SocialProfile implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SocialProfileId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="social_network_id")
    public SocialNetwork getSocialNetwork() {
        return socialNetwork;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** sorry, i have mixed annotations on fields and methods on my answer ... never do that ! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll accept this but I decided to go with a surrogate key like stg suggested in the comments above, makes things much simpler.

Comment: yes having a simple id is much more simpler ... i just answered to your question here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Pras has said, we can even move the @ManyToOne inside the @Embeddable class itself so SocialProfileId will look like, where you can clearly see in your Embedded class itself that it referencing another table

```
@Embeddable
public class SocialProfileId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User userId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "social_network_id")
    private SocialNetwork socialNetworkId;

    public SocialProfileId(User userId, SocialNetwork socialNetworkId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.socialNetworkId = socialNetworkId;
    }

}
```

And your SocialProfile entity can simply have the embedded class and other fields like email and so on..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "social_profile")
public class SocialProfile implements java.io.Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SocialProfileId id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need mamy-to-many mapping having join-table with extra column.
For this you need to create 2 more classes.

FYI : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

My problem for a REST application was similar but a little bit different, I will post it here.
I had 2 data tables: **Song** & **Tag** with an id each (songid, tagid).
Then I had a table for joining them together **Tagassignment** which only had both of the primary keys from **Song** and **Tag**. So I did not want to join them, I wanted to keep the table with both foreign keys.

Source of my solution: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id

---

## Before

**Song**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "songs")
data class Song(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Int,

    ...
)
```

**Tag**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
data class Tag(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id: Int,

    ...
)
```

**Tagassignment**

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tagassignment")
 data class Tagassignment(

     val songid: Int,

     val tagid: Int

 )
```

---

## After

I did not change **Song** and **Tag**.

**Tagassignment**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(value = TagassignmentKey::class)
@Table(name = "tagassignment")
data class Tagassignment(

    @Id
    val songid: Int,

    @Id
    val tagid: Int

)
```

and I created a Key class

**TagassignmentKey**

```
class TagassignmentKey(val songid: Int, val tagid: Int) : Serializable {

    constructor() : this(0, 0)

}
```